# Canvas Rotation in Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

My Canvas (red) does not align with it's parent grid when I have small grid width. It should also be in the middle when grid width is smaller than canvas height. How can I solve?

```
<Grid x:Name="playergroup" Margin="0,0,0,0" Background="#FF97219C" >
        <Canvas x:Name="LVCanvas"  Margin="0,0,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5" Width="450"  Height="300" Background="#FFF11A1A" >
            <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
                </TransformGroup>
          </Canvas.RenderTransform>
        </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

[image: huge parent width]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the Canvas's horizontal and vertical alignment to `Center`:

```
<Grid Background="#FF97219C" Width="200">
    <Canvas Width="450" Height="300" Background="#FFF11A1A"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
            RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Canvas.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Canvas.RenderTransform>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

Comment: great, I tried so many things but this solved my problem. thanks!